# Using the label of a ChoiceField in Django Rest Framework instead of the choice id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to override my choicefield in DRF, especially I want to return django group as ChoiceField in `OPTIONS`

Eg:

My Group Models are,

```
id   group_name
1    Lead
2    Admin
3    Junior
4    Senior
```

I want to return Group Name as choices in http request OPTIONS

How do I do it?